# Converting date formats python - Unusual date formats - Extract %Y%M%D

Tags: python, date, strftime, strptime

I have a large data set with a variety of Date information in the following formats:

- DAYS since Jan 1, 1900 - ex: 41213 -  I believe these are from Excel  http://www.kirix.com/stratablog/jd-edwards-date-conversions-cyyddd
- YYDayofyear - ex 2012265

I am familiar with python's time module, strptime() method, and strftime () method.  However, I am not sure what these date formats above are called on if there is a python module I can use to convert these unusual date formats.

Any idea how to get the %Y%M%D format from these unusual date formats without writing my own calculator?

Thanks.

Comment: what's your input format????

Comment: "days since 1900-01-01" are NOT Excel dates. Formatting the number 41213 as a date in Excel produces 2012-10-31, not 2012-11-02

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can try something like the following:

```
In [1]: import datetime

In [2]: s = '2012265'

In [3]: datetime.datetime.strptime(s, '%Y%j')
Out[3]: datetime.datetime(2012, 9, 21, 0, 0)

In [4]: d = '41213'

In [5]: datetime.date(1900, 1, 1) + datetime.timedelta(int(d))
Out[5]: datetime.date(2012, 11, 2)
```

The first one is the trickier one, but it uses the `%j` parameter to interpret the day of the year you provide (after a four-digit year, represented by `%Y`). The second one is simply the number of days since January 1, 1900.

This is the general conversion - not sure of your input format but hopefully this can be tweaked to suit it.

Comment: Awesome answer.  Didn't know about the %j parameter.  Thanks

Answer (score 4):

On the Excel integer to Python datetime bit:

Note that there are two Excel date systems (one 1-Jan-1900 based and another 1-Jan 1904 based); see https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/214330/differences-between-the-1900-and-the-1904-date-system-in-excel for more information.

Also note that the system is NOT zero-based.  So, in the 1900 system, 1-Jan-1900 is day 1 (not day 0).

```
import datetime

EXCEL_DATE_SYSTEM_PC=1900
EXCEL_DATE_SYSTEM_MAC=1904

i = 42129  # Excel number for 5-May-2015
d = datetime.date(EXCEL_DATE_SYSTEM_PC, 1, 1) + datetime.timedelta(i-2)
```

Comment: Minus 2 on the timedelta is key to aligning perfectly with Excel. This answer is preferred to the others here (currently voted higher!) as it is more accurate.

Answer (score 2):

Both of these formats seems pretty straightforward to work with. The first one, in fact, is just an integer, so why don't you just do something like this?

```
import datetime

def days_since_jan_1_1900_to_datetime(d):
    return datetime.datetime(1900,1,1) + \
        datetime.timedelta(days=d)
```

For the second one, the details depend on exactly how the format is defined (e.g. can you always expect 3 digits after the year even when the number of days is less than 100, or is it possible that there are 2 or 1 – and if so, is the year always 4 digits?) but once you've got that part down it can be done very similarly.

Answer (score 0):

According to http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior
, day of the year is "%j", whereas the first case can be solved by toordinal() and fromordinal(): `date.fromordinal(date(1900, 1, 1).toordinal() + x)`

Answer (score 0):

I'd think timedelta.

```
import datetime
d = datetime.timedelta(days=41213)
start = datetime.datetime(year=1900, month=1, day=1)
the_date = start + d
```

For the second one, you can `2012265[:4]` to get the year and use the same method.

edit: See the answer with `%j` for the second.

Answer (score 0):

```
from datetime import datetime 

df(['timeelapsed'])=(pd.to_datetime(df['timeelapsed'], format='%H:%M:%S') - datetime(1900, 1, 1)).dt.total_seconds()
```