# Changing date format after converting from int value in python

Tags: python

Is it possible to change format of date from (YYYY,MM,DD) to (DD,MM,YYYY)..

```
import datetime    
date_value = 41381.0    
date_conv= datetime.date(1900, 1, 1) + datetime.timedelta(int(date_value))    
print date_conv
```

output:

```
date_conv = 2013-04-19
```

[Converting date formats python - Unusual date formats - Extract %Y%M%D](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14271791/converting-date-formats-python-unusual-date-formats-extract-ymd?answertab=votes#tab-top)

current output is in (YYYY,MM,DD) formate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
>>> import datetime
>>> date_value = 41381.0
>>> date_conv= datetime.date(1900, 1, 1) + datetime.timedelta(int(date_value))
>>> print date_conv.strftime('%d-%m-%Y')
19-04-2013
```

Answer (score 6):

```
print date_conv.strftime('%d.%m.%Y')
```

prints the date in `DD.MM.YYYY` format. More formatting options [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior).